# Paypal Express Checkout: No review option

Tags: paypal

I am currently implementing a very simple paypal checkout option on a website. For this I am using Express Checkout (Client side version).

It works just fine, but the dialog informs the user, that they will be able to review the order before confirming. However, when they click "continue" the payment instantly goes through.
If you look at their full working demo, you can see, that it is just what happens:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

This seems highly inconvenient.
Is there any way I can get express checkout to show that review page?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `commit: true` in the button options.